# Recorded AAC audio in Android does not play on iOS devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native, audio-recording

AAC audio recorded in Android is not playing on iOS devices. Here is the code example of how we are recording audio in Android devices. When we try to play that audio in an iOS device using `react-native-sound`, it does not play on iOS device and getting an error as below.

**Failed to load the sound**
and iOS exception read as below.

> Objectcode: "ENSOSSTATUSERRORDOMAIN1937337955"domain:
> "NSOSStatusErrorDomain"message: "The operation couldn't be completed.
> (OSStatus error 1937337955.)"nativeStackIOS: Array[17]userInfo:
> Object__proto__: Object

```
AudioRecorder.prepareRecordingAtPath('/path/to/audio/test.aac', {
        SampleRate: 22050,
        Channels: 1,
        AudioQuality: "Low",
        AudioEncoding: "aac",
        AudioEncodingBitRate: 32000
});
```

We are using **RN 0.41** and [react-native-audio 3.2.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio)

Did anyone face similar issue? let me know if there is any misconfiguration.

Comment: Try changing the extension to .m4a.

Comment: @shallowThought I have tried to .m4a but got the same error.

Comment: have you solved this? I am using the `.aac` sample from [here](http://techslides.com/sample-files-for-development) and it throws this error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Error Message. My solution was to add `OutputFormat: 'aac_adts'`.

```
AudioRecorder.prepareRecordingAtPath(completePath, {
        SampleRate: 22050,
        Channels: 1,
        AudioQuality: "Low",
        AudioEncoding: "aac",
        OutputFormat: 'aac_adts'
      })
```

`OutputFormat: 'aac_adts'` is only needed on Android. It overrides the default `OutputFormat: 'mpeg_4'`.